# Determining the value of c in a geometric distribution example

Tags: probability

I'm currently trying to solve an example that goes as follows:

> Determine the value of $c$ so that each of the following functions can serve as a probability distribution of the random variable $x$.
>
> $p(x) = c(0.3)^{x-1}$ for $x = 1,2,\ldots$

I took the following approach to solve it:

First of all I'm given the first number in the sequence which is $1$ so from that if I start working out the equation of $p(x)$ then I will get $p(1) = c$. From there I can stop because the total probability (summation) is equal to one and that's what I got from $p(1)$ since $c = 1$.

Is my way of approaching the question right ? Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum 
$$\sum_1^\infty c(0.3)^{x-1}\tag{1}$$
of all the probabilities has to be equal to $1$.

But the series (1) is an infinite geometric series. By a standard formula, it has sum $\frac{c}{1-0.3}$.

Thus $c=0.7$.

**Remark:** Suppose that a certain experiment has probability of success $p$. Repeat the experiment until you get the first success. Then the number $X$ of trials required has *geometric distribution*, and for $x=1,2,3\dots$, we have
$$\Pr(X=x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}.$$
Yours is the case $1-p=0.3$, meaning that $p=0.7$.

Comment: Clearly explained but I have a question, how did (1-0.3) end up in the denominator?

Comment: You may remember the following formula. If $|r|\lt 1$ then $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots=\frac{a}{1-r}$.  Ours is the case $a=c$ and $r=0.3$. The formula is not hard to prove formally. Informally, it comes down to $(1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots)=1$. (If you multiply out, almost all the terms cancel. I can produce a more formal proof tomorrow if you want.

Comment: That's alright, I got your point, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The series
$$
c\sum_{x=1}^\infty(0.3)^{x-1}
$$
must be equal to $1$.

We have that
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty(0.3)^{x-1}=\sum_{x=0}^\infty(0.3)^{x}=\frac1{1-0.3}=\frac{10}7
$$
so $c$ must be equal to $0.7$.